# how to define origin_check in pywebio start_server

Tags: python, tornado

I have a small test script where I'd like to check the pywebio start_server arguments. But neither `allowed_origins` nor `check_origin` seems to work in my script:

```
from pywebio import start_server
from pywebio.input import *
from pywebio.output import *

def main():
    put_markdown("## just a small start_server test")

def my_origin_check(value):
    print(value)
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server(main, check_origin=my_origin_check, debug=True, port=5000)
```

I can't see the reason why `my_origin_check` doesn't get called - I'm blind on my eyes ... any help?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the source code](https://github.com/pywebio/PyWebIO/blob/dev/pywebio/platform/tornado.py#L250) of `start_server()`:

```py
check_origin_func = lambda origin, handler: _is_same_site(origin, handler) or check_origin(origin)
```

the user-defined `check_origin` function only is called when the application url and the underlying websocket api is not on same host

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31795088)